# Inheriting from implementation of LinkedList to a SortedLinkedList, access private Node

Tags: java, linked-list, sortedlist

I am quite new to Java and I am trying to do my own implementation of a Linked List and then extend that to a Sorted Linked List.

I think my problem is that the SortedLinkedList class that inherits from LinkedList and > dont have access to the private Node start; in the LinkedList. This is a simplification of the code.

I start by creating my own Interface of the List class

```
interface List<T> {
public int size();            
public void add(int pos, T x);  
public void add(T x);                 
public T get(int pos);             
public T remove();                   
}
```

And saves this as List.java and then I create my linked list class

```
class LinkedList<T> implements List<T> {

//Starting point of the Linked List
private Node start;

public class Node {
    T x;
    Node next;

    public Node(T x) {
        this.x= x;
    }
    public T getValue(){
      return x;
    }
}

//Here is implementations of all the methods from List<T> and some ohers
}
```

This all works as expected, and I have tested all the methods and confirmed that they are working. But now I want to use this class to create another class that inherits from LinkedList and also uses Comparable so I can sort values while I enter them. I get everything set up and creates the class

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends LinkedList<T>{


//And here I try to do something like 
@Override
public void add(T x){
    //add logic to add a element
}

}
```

And here I have tried lots of different things. But no matter how I create the method it wont add any new Nodes. I think the problem have to do with the methods not beeing able to access the private Node start from LinkedList. Becuse I can for instance use the add function from LinkedList to just add a element in the same way by doing

```
@Override
public void add(T x){
super.add(x);
}
```

And when I tried to just add the methods from LinkedList directly inside SortedLinkedList and changed it to

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>>{

}
```

I did manage to use the compareTo() and Override the add method.

I know this got long, but I hope someone can enlighten me on this. I did try to create a getter and setter method inside LinkedList but I didnt manage to get that to compile in any way without errors.

Comment: The `private` access modifier implies nothing outside that class (except in specific cases with nested classes) can access the field. Set it as `protected` to allow access from child classes.

Comment: Well you're asking why your method LinkedList.add is not working but you didn't share its implementation.

Comment: Changing it to protected seemed to work. Rob I didnt share the add implementation since I know it was working both inside the LinkedList and also when I called it using super.add() from the SortedLinkedList class

Comment: @Siesta From a behaviour you're describing its implementation can't be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JLS states (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2):

```
Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of 
that class. Only members of a class that are declared protected or public are 
inherited by subclasses declared in a package other than the one in which the 
class is declared.
```

You're most likely working with private `start` variable in your add() implementation in `LinkedList` class.

To resolve the issue just change the access modifier to protected:

```
protected Node start;
```